# gnuplot animation multiple data files hold on after do loop

Tags: animation, gnuplot, animated-gif

I'm animating from two data files.

I need to "hold-on" after first do loop and then replot second do loop for animation.

See below an example:

```
set term gif size 400,400 animate delay 100 loop 0 optimize font 'Verdana,10' crop
set output "output.gif"
set yrange [0:4]                                        
set xrange [0:5]

$data1 << EOD
2.24448 0.270645    1.00    1.00
3.24448 0.270645    0.500   1.20
1.24448 0.411645    0.600   1.60
EOD

$data2 << EOD
3.24448 2.50645    0.400    1.00
0.24448 2.30645    0.800   1.20
1.24448 2.50000    0.300   0.60
1.55448 2.21645    0.300   1.30
EOD

stats $data1 using 1:4 nooutput
n1 = int(STATS_records) - 1

stats $data2 using 1:4 nooutput
n2 = int(STATS_records) - 1

plot x

do for [i=0:n1] {
    replot $data1 u 1:2:3:4 every ::0::i w vectors lw 1.5 lc rgb "red" notitle
}

do for [i=0:n2] {
    replot $data2 u 1:2:3:4 every ::0::i w vectors lw 1.5 lc rgb "blue" notitle
}

set output
```

The output is as follows: The red vectors are created from `data1` and blue vectors are created from `data2`.

I want to first animate the red vectors and hold on and then start animating blue vectors. As it stands now, when the blue vector appears red vector disappears and reappears. I just want to simply start animating red vector 1 by one and then followed by blue vector.

See below: Red vector appears as planned, but as soon as blue vector appears, red vector disappears and then starts to animate, I just want to follow the sequence, first plot red vector and hold on and then continue to animate blue vector.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `replot` has a special behaviour... (but I don't remember the details).
Therefore, I would do it without `replot` as follows.

**Code:**

```
### animated vectors
reset session
set term gif size 400,400 animate delay 100 optimize font 'Verdana,10' crop
set output "output.gif"
set yrange [0:4]
set xrange [0:5]

$data1 << EOD
2.24448 0.270645    1.00    1.00
3.24448 0.270645    0.500   1.20
1.24448 0.411645    0.600   1.60
EOD

$data2 << EOD
3.24448 2.50645    0.400    1.00
0.24448 2.30645    0.800   1.20
1.24448 2.50000    0.300   0.60
1.55448 2.21645    0.300   1.30
EOD

stats $data1 using 1:4 nooutput
n1 = int(STATS_records) - 1

stats $data2 using 1:4 nooutput
n2 = int(STATS_records) - 1

plot x

do for [i=0:n1] {
    plot x, \
    $data1 u 1:2:3:4 every ::0::i w vectors lw 1.5 lc rgb "red" notitle
}

do for [i=0:n2] {
    plot x, \
    for [j=0:n1] $data1 u 1:2:3:4 every ::0::j w vectors lw 1.5 lc rgb "red" notitle, \
    $data2 u 1:2:3:4 every ::0::i w vectors lw 1.5 lc rgb "blue" notitle
}
set output
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:** (merging 3 or more files)

**Data:**

`File1.dat`

```
2.24448 0.270645    1.00    1.00
3.24448 0.270645    0.500   1.20
1.24448 0.411645    0.600   1.60
```

`File2.dat`

```
3.24448 2.50645    0.400    1.00
0.24448 2.30645    0.800   1.20
1.24448 2.50000    0.300   0.60
1.55448 2.21645    0.300   1.30
```

`File3.dat`

```
4.0  1.0  -1.0   1.0
1.0  2.0   0.5   0.7
4.0  3.0  -1.0  -0.5
1.0  3.0   0.5  -1.0
```

**Code:**

```
### animated vectors from several files
reset session
set term gif size 400,400 animate delay 100 optimize font 'Verdana,10' crop
set output "output.gif"
set yrange [0:4]
set xrange [0:5]

set table $Arrows
    plot 'File1.dat' u 1:2:3:4:('0xff0000') w table
    plot 'File2.dat' u 1:2:3:4:('0x0000ff') w table
    plot 'File3.dat' u 1:2:3:4:('0x00ff00') w table
unset table

plot x

do for [i=1:|$Arrows|] {
    plot x, \
    $Arrows u 1:2:3:4:5 every ::0::i-1 w vec lw 1.5 lc rgb var notitle
}
set output
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: actually, another solution would be to merge the datablocks and add a column for the color. Then plot this single datablock with `linecolor variable`.